# ng2-translate (404 not found) I've added it in system.js

Tags: javascript, angular

I've installed ng2-translate to my proj and console error keep showing 404 of the bundle and xhr error. I've added ng2-translate to my system.config.js that comes with the standard angular2 quickstart but still showing 404 and xhr error.

It's either giving me 404 error or annotation of undefined error :/

github: thread regarding the issue using systemconfig.js

https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate/issues/167

```js
var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'ng2-translate':              'node_modules/ng2-translate',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
```

Edit:

```js
var packages = {
    'ng2-translate':              { main: 'ng2-translate.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

I faced to the same issue today

solution is this:

put `'ng2-translate': 'node_modules/ng2-translate/bundles'` in `system.config.js` in the map and  `'ng2-translate' : { defaultExtension: 'js' }` in packages

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had to map it like this, in the `systemjs` config to make it work:

```
'ng2-translate': 'npm:ng2-translate/bundles/ng2-translate.umd.js'
```

Answer (score 1):

install the npm module:

```
npm install ng2-translate --save
```

update your config like this:

```
System.config({
    packages: {
        "ng2-translate": {main: 'ng2-translate.js', "defaultExtension": "js"}
    },
    map: {
        'ng2-translate': 'node_modules/ng2-translate'
    }
});
```

Use ng2-translate like this in .ts file-

```
import {TranslateService, TranslatePipe} from 'ng2-translate';
```

See if this helps.

Comment: that's what I did :) i've already installed the package to my proj that system.config is pretty much what the angular2 installation guide has.

Answer (score 1):

Probably by doing:

```
 'ng2-translate':              'node_modules/ng2-translate',
```

you are referring index.js

however you might need to point some else .js file such as

```
 'ng2-translate':              'node_modules/ng2-translate/somefile.js',
```

for example you can do:

```
System.config({
    //... some other stuff
      map: {
        'ng2-translate': 'node_modules/ng2-translate/ng2-translate.js',
    },
    packages: {          
        //... some other stuff, do not put your ng2-translate here
    }
});
```

Comment: Did that too, and its giving me an error regarding annotation of undefined, see my edit in my original post. And if I do that it looks like this "http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-translate.js/ng2-translate 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: I get npm ng2-translate and exact file you need to refer is `ng2-translate.js` Dont forget `.js` extention

Comment: @asd_enel_hak Yeah if you check my edit in my original post I've included pretty .js extension. I get "Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined"

Comment: supress in packages section, `while(succes) doCombinations();` :))

Comment: I'm confused, put that where?

Comment: I was joking with `while loop` :) I was trying to say do combinations until it works, for example: do not use `var packages = {
    'ng2-translate':              { main: 'ng2-translate.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };`

Comment: see my first comment on your post. result of that is --"localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-translate.js/ng2-translate"

Answer (score 1):

ng2-translate uses the CommonJS module format as configured in its tsconfig.json:

```
compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
     ...
}
```

I successfully added ng2-translate by explicitly specifying this format in the packages section of my SystemJS config.

```
System.config({
    map: {
        'ng2-translate': 'node_modules/ng2-translate'
         // ... more mappings
    },
    packages: {          
        'ng2-bootstrap': {
             defaultExtension: 'js',
             format: 'cjs'
        }
        // ... more package definitions
    }
});
```

Refer to the list of [supported module formats](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md/) in the SystemJS documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If like me, you've spent hours trying to fix the ng2-translate (404 not found) issue. Here's is a systemjs.config.js which worked for me. Compliment of Sam Verschueren @[github](https://github.com/SamVerschueren)

```
(function(global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
    };

    var paths = {
        'underscore':                 'node_modules/underscore/underscore.js',
        'ng2-translate':              'node_modules/ng2-translate/bundles/ng2-translate.umd.js'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ng2-translate':              { defaultExtension: 'js' }
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'forms',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated',
        'upgrade',
    ];
    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages,
        paths: paths
    };
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a i18n folder in your app with en.json (its the default setting) or whatever file you call from the constructor, looks like:

```
constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
    // this language will be used as a fallback when a translation isn't found in the current language
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');

     // the lang to use, if the lang isn't available, it will use the current loader to get them
    translate.use('en');
}
```